# Why is my Chrome back button skipping pages when using Google Reader's "Next" bookmarklet?

Tags: google-chrome

The "[Next](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109000953/http://geekswithblogs.net/paulwhitblog/archive/2007/08/13/Social-content-in-context-with-Google-Readers-Next-bookmarklet.aspx)" google reader bookmarklet is a bookmark button you put in your bookmark bar, and when you click on it, it redirects you to the next unread item in you google reader list, but not in google reader. It shows you the original page.(If you go to Google Reader settings > goodies, you'll find it.)

My problem:
When using the **next** bookmarklet for many times in a row, sometimes with 2-3 seconds of interval to skip uninteresting stuff, sometimes I want to go back to the previous, and when I click the browser **back button**, it often skips some 2-5 pages and goes to a very previous one, and not the one I was expecting.

If I use the backspace instead of the back icon, it skips it aswell, and if I right-click the back icon, it doesn't show the history for the one I was looking for.
It happens on normal, beta and dev versions of chrome.
In Firefox it does not skip.

Comment: Any site in particular that seems to break it? (Or, to which you seem to be taken back to?)

Comment: it happens to all the sites I guess.

Comment: seems random. It even skips when its only feeds from one site, and it brings you back to a previous one from that same site.

Comment: It seems they solved this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has always been a problem with AJAX-based sites. Search for "Breaking the BACK button" in google, and you'll find many articles. The problem is that AJAX queries don't get added to the browser's history, so the "BACK" button doesn't even see them.

Many Google products try to "fix" this by doing navigation in hidden IFRAMEs, sometimes in combination with anchor-names in the URLs (although the anchor names are really for bookmarks, and not for this, since they don't usually get saved into the browser's history.)

Comment: Yeah, I get this, but in firefox it does not skip. :(

Comment: The thing is, that it does appear in the history - hit ctrl-H and you get the full list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the browser back button? Because if you want to go back up, just use the Google Reader shortcuts:

- j/k = item down/up = selects the next/previous item in the list
- space/shift-space = page down/up = moves the page down/up
- n/p = scan down/up = in list view, selects the next item without opening it
- o = open/close item = in list view, expands or collapses the selected item
- enter = open/close item = in list view, expands or collapses the selected item
- s = toggle star = stars the selected item
- shift-s = toggle share = shares the selected item
- m = mark as read/unread = switches the read state of the selected item
- t = tag an item = opens the tagging field for the selected item
- v = view original = opens the original source for this article in a new window
- shift-a = mark all as read = marks all items in the current view as read
- 1 = expanded view = displays the subscription as expanded items
- 2 = list view = displays the subscription as a list of headlines
- r = refresh = refreshes the unread counts in the navigation
- shift-n/p = navigation down/up = selects the next/previous subscription or folder in  the navigation
- shift-x = navigation expand/collapse = expand or collapse a folder selected in the navigation
- shift-o = navigation open subscription = opens the item currently selected in the navigation
- gh = go to home = goes to the Google Reader homepage
- ga = go to all items = goes to the "All items" view
- gs = go to starred items = goes to the "Starred items" view
- gt = go to tag = allows you to navigate to a tag by entering the tag name
- gu = go to subscription = allows you to navigate to a subscription by entering the subscription name
- u = toggle full screen mode = hides and shows the list of subscriptions
- ? = keyboard shortcuts help = displays a quick guide to all of Reader's shortcuts

Comment: I'm using the reader bookmarklet which gets me to the next unread item BUT without using reader. It opens the original website.

If you go to google reader settings > goodies, you'll find it.

I prefer looking at the real sites than inside reader. It's just me.

Comment: Ah in that case I misunderstood your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Google recently put an interstitial page into the Next button which fixes the back button.